# JS how to break loop

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>circle</title>
  <style>
    .circle {
      width: 32px;
      height: 32px;
      border-radius: 32px;
      background: darkred
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="circle" id="ball" style="position:relative; left: 20px; top: 400px;"></div>
  <input type="text" onkeypress="pressFunction(event)">
  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    function pressFunction(event) {
      var x = event.which;

      if (parseInt(x, 10) == 119) {
        jump();
      }
    }

    function jumpup() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "hey"
      document.getElementById("ball").style.top = parseInt(document.getElementById("ball").style.top, 10) + parseInt(10, 10) + "px";
    }

    function jumpdown() {
      document.getElementById("ball").style.top = parseInt(document.getElementById("ball").style.top, 10) + parseInt(-10, 10) + "px";
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "no"
    }

    var jumpingup = window.setInterval(function() {
      jumpup()
    }, 50);
    var jumpingdown = window.setInterval(function() {
      jumpdown()
    }, 50);

    function jump() {
      jumpingup;
      setTimeout(clearInterval(jumpingup), 100);
      jumpingdown;
      setTimeou(clearInterval(jumpingdown), 100);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
function jump(){
    window.setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("ball").style.top= parseInt(document.getElementById("ball").style.top, 10) + parseInt(speedy,10) +"px"; 
}, 20)
    window.setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("ball").style.top= parseInt(document.getElementById("ball").style.top, 10) + parseInt(-1*speedy,10) +"px"; 
}, 20)
}
```

I have a ball and I want to raise this ball with `window.setInterval(function())` then move back its coordinates. I thought I can execute `window.setInterval(function())` for a period of time then break it but I couldn't figure how can I break a loop. Is there any way to do it?

```
    function jumpup(){
    document.getElementById("ball").style.top= parseInt(document.getElementById("ball").style.top, 10) + parseInt(10,10) +"px"; 
}
    function jumpdown(){
    document.getElementById("ball").style.top= parseInt(document.getElementById("ball").style.top, 10) + parseInt(-10,10) +"px"; 
}

    var jumpingup = window.setInterval(function(){jumpup() }, 20);
    var jumpingdown = window.setInterval(function(){jumpdown() }, 20);

    function jump(){
    jumpingup;
    setTimeout(clearInterval(jumpingup),40);
    jumpingdown;
    setTimeou(clearInterval(jumpingdown),40);
    }
```

I make some changes but still I can't do it what I want

https://jsbin.com/docixofexi/edit?html

Comment: [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval), providing you store the intervals' identifiers (returned by `setInterval()`).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski that helped me actualy so that I can setTimeout a period of time then clear Interval nice

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>circle</title>
  <style>
    .circle {
      width: 32px;
      height: 32px;
      border-radius: 32px;
      background: darkred
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="circle" id="ball" style="position:relative; left: 20px; top: 400px;"></div>
  <input type="text" onkeypress="pressFunction(event)">
  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    function pressFunction(event) {
      var x = event.which;

      if (parseInt(x, 10) == 119) {
        jump();
      }
    }
    var jumpingdown = window.setInterval(function() {
      jumpdown()
    }, 50);
    clearInterval(jumpingdown);

    function jumpup() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "hey"
      document.getElementById("ball").style.top = parseInt(document.getElementById("ball").style.top, 10) + parseInt(-20, 10) + "px";
    }

    function jumpdown() {
      document.getElementById("ball").style.top = parseInt(document.getElementById("ball").style.top, 10) + parseInt(10, 10) + "px";
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "no"
    }

    function jump() {
      var jumpingup = window.setInterval(function() {
        jumpup()
      }, 30);
      setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(jumpingup)
      }, 230);
      var jumpingdown = window.setInterval(function() {
        jumpdown()
      }, 30);
      setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(jumpingdown)
      }, 460);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

1. I make jumpup function which will raise the ball
2. I make jumpdown function which will turn back to balls old position
3. then I make a loop to jumpup with `window.setInterval(function())`
4. then I set and timer to run `clearInterval()` with `setTimeout`

so that I got a loop which is ending in 0.46 sec